# Как кастомизировать компонент Битрикс 1с?

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть компонент форма обратной связи, хочу получать в нее некоторые значения из инфоблока, по типу того как получаю такие значения в компоненте новость детально. Так вот, что и в каком файле нужно дописать что бы в шаблоне компонента я смог получать свойства элементов конкретного инфоблока (например id 5)?

Пробовал объединять файлы .parameters.php и component.php но так ничего и не вышло. В интернете гуглил в похожих вопросах ссылку все дают на документацию битрикса, а так вроде написано все понятно а как это применить ничерта не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать файл `result_modifier.php` рядом с `template.php` и там выбирать нужные данные и записывать их в массив `$arResult`.

И уже в `template.php` отображать их или делать то, что вам нужно.

https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2830